# Trigger click on element dynamically created by AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, click

I'm using AngularJS to create a new  tag in order to download a csv file. Below the code I use to trigger the download. The download starts on Chrome but not in Firefox. Do you have any clue why this happens?

```
var element = angular.element('<a/>');
element.attr({
   href: exportedString,
   target: '_self',
   download: 'test.csv'
})[0].click();
```

**EDIT:** Firefox needs an existent DOM

JS:

```
var linkElem = $("#link");
var element = angular.element(linkElem);
```

HTML:

```
<a ng-hide=true id="link"></a>
```

**EDIT 2:** On Chrome, the downloaded file name is "download" and not the passed value ("test.csv" in this case). Any suggestions?

Here there is also a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1FxQ143wBI1sWSDJFpTF?p=preview)

Comment: I wonder if it could be a bug in latest Chrome...

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in Chrome 35 reported in [issue #377860](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373182).

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816005/anchor-tag-download-attribute-not-working-bug-in-chrome-35-0-1916-114) answer for more details

I updated your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ocM6tUiULqm084xTTBQB?p=preview) solution.

Basically you need to use it like follow:

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
var blob = new Blob([$scope.exportContent], {
  type: 'text/csv'
});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
element.href = url;
element.setAttribute('download', 'test.csv');
document.body.appendChild(element); //Append the element to work in firefox
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get both Chrome & FF to work, I actually found that I had to first check to see if element[0] was undefined (which it was in Chrome but not FF):

```
var link = $("#reportDownloadLink");
var element = angular.element(link)
    .attr('href', dataUrl)
    .attr('download', data.FileDownloadName)
    .attr('target', '_blank');
(element[0] || element).click();
```