# Anchor tag download attribute not working :Bug in Chrome 35.0.1916.114

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am trying to [refer to this code](http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/) where a we are downloading a CSV file on click of a link.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
            colDelim = '","',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                var $row = $(row),
                    $cols = $row.find('td');

                return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col),
                        text = $col.text();

                    return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes

                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

            }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

            // Data URI
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        $(this)
            .attr({
            'download': filename,
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank'
        });
    }

    // This must be a hyperlink
    $(".export").on('click', function (event) {
        // CSV
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);

        // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
        // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
    });
});
```

But somehow, the downloaded file is named as `download` without extension in Chrome v35.0.1916.114 , one workaround was to change data:application/csv to data:text/csv, but that only helped in getting the extension correct in the downloaded file i.e. it now downloads as `download.csv`.

The issue with the download attribute still remains. I wanted to name my file as `export.csv`, but it still gives me `download.csv`.

Comment: I was running Chrome 34.  Downloaded as "export.csv", upgraded to 35 downloaded as "download".  Seems like a chrome bug to me.

Comment: Yes... so is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Just file a bug and wait for a fix to be released (I'm running into this same issue). It will probably be very soon. If you can't wait you'll have to send the csv down to the server with an ajax request so you can serve it back up.

Comment: So can i use nodejs http proxy server and get it from there? if so can someone give me any pointers how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912198/anchors-download-property-is-not-working-on-some-pages-gmail seems to work see jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pnMH2/

Comment: I confirm this happens here too, only "download" without extension downloads, should be "export.csv" any quick fix on this or Google news  about it ?

Comment: This bug has been fixed in Chrome 36, released July 16, 2014. Your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/) now works again!

Answer (score 29):

So you should change this:

```
// Data URI
csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

$(this)
    .attr({
    'download': filename,
        'href': csvData,
        'target': '_blank'
});
```

To This

```
// Data URI
//csvData = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv), //old way
blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' }); //new way
var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

$(this)
.attr({
    'download': filename,
    'href': csvUrl
});
```

And it should work!

Comment: right, blob still works with download attribute correctly. here is a demo: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html

Comment: This works great!  Probably an even better solution than using data

Comment: This should be the accepted solution imo. Works like a charm.

Comment: I actually need `'target': '_blank'` to make it work...Chrome 37

Comment: @Mathew Thanks, you saved my day. I use

    `var universalBOM = "\uFEFF";
    //var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(universalBOM + CSV);
    var blob = new Blob([universalBOM, CSV], {type: 'application/xls;charset=UTF-8', encoding:"UTF-8"}); //new way
    var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);`

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug in Chrome 35 reported in issue #377860.

Update: This bug was merged into [issue #373182](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373182). You can click the star to tell the devs you think this issue should get fixed and also get notified of changes.

Typically the chromium team releases an update every 2 weeks so you can expect a fix soon since this is marked as *Pri-1* which I assume means highest priority.

Comment: Looks like it's fixed as of June 20th, 2014.

Comment: I don't think it's fixed, I'm still having this issue.

Comment: I just started having this issue after switching an old version of jquery to the latest. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

For me worked:

```
var content = "some content";
var link = document.createElement('a');
var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", content]);
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download', 'file.csv');
link.click();
```

Comment: This is not working in iOS. If i want to make it work in iOS, then how can i make it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit that worked for me (in Chrome and Firefox).  I'm building a xls file out of a table.

```
  function downloadInnerHtml(filename,elId,mimeType){
    var elHtml='<table border="1">'+document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML+'</table>';
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    mimeType=mimeType || 'application/xls';

    var blob=new Blob([elHtml],{type:mimeType});
    var url=URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.href=url;

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.innerHTML = "Export to CSV";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  }

  $(document).on("click","#exportButton",function(){
    var date=new Date();
    var mm=date.getMonth()+1;
    var dd=date.getDate();
    var yy=date.getFullYear();
    var timeStamp=yy+""+((mm<10)?"0"+mm:mm)+""+((dd<10)?"0"+dd:dd);
    var fileName=timeStamp+'_Employees.xls';
    downloadInnerHtml(fileName,'mainEmployeeTable','application/xls');
  });
```

Hope that helps someone else...

--Charles

Comment: why do we keep on getting pop-up: *The file format and extension of download.xls don't match.* ?

Comment: Aakash, try changing that to text/csv. Since it looks like you were trying to pull a CSV instead of an XLS.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this code, I was not able to get results in IE plus this code only iterates over `td`, it will skip any `th` present in your table. I have modified the code to resolve both the issues I was facing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

            var $rows = $table.find('tr'),
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11),
            tmpHeadDelim = String.fromCharCode(11),
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0),
            colDelim = '","',
            headDelim = '","',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td');
                $heads = $row.find('th');

                var c = $heads.map(function (k, head) {
                    var $head = $(head),
                    text = $head.text();
                    return text.replace(/"/g, '""');
                }).get().join(tmpHeadDelim);

                var d = $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();
                    return text.replace(/"/g, '""');
                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

            return (c+d);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpHeadDelim).join(headDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"';


        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        // if Internet Explorer (10+)
        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
            var blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(csv)], {
                    type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8'
            });
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        }
        else {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            var blob = new Blob([csv],{type:'text/csv;charset=utf8'});
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', filename);
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        }
    }

    $("#fnExcelReport").on('click', function (event) {
        var args = [$('#tableContent'), 'Report.csv'];
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, args);
    });
});
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Aakash_Goplani/pen/BmQwZO)

Answer (score -1):

append anchor tag using string add tag information in string and then append, it works for me for google chrome