# Exporting highcharts data to CSV file

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I've tried to use the Highcharts export feature as exampled on their site: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/cqjvD/ but I would like to be able to download the csv file instead of alerting/displaying it.

Here is my chart: http://jsfiddle.net/uF4H7/10/

The code for displaying the csv is simple, you just add:

```
$('#getcsv').click(function () {
   alert(chart.getCSV());
 });
```

Can this be done in html/js/highcharts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the following http://jsfiddle.net/uF4H7/11/

```
$('#getcsv').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    alert(chart.getCSV());
    window.open();
    //this line was added to your code to download the CSV
    window.open("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(chart.getCSV()));
});
```

The following line tells browser to open the data in the new window - browsers do not recognize text/csv mime it so they ask you to download the CSV file

```
window.open("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(chart.getCSV()));
```

Or you could use the new feature of HTML - the link which forces to download with `download` attribute. In your case add this code to javascript:

```
$('#getcsvAnchor').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    $(this).attr('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,'+escape(chart.getCSV())); 
    $(this).attr('download', "data-visualisation.csv");
});
```

And this to your HTML - link to download:

```
<a id="getcsvAnchor" href="#">download</a>
```

The javascript gets the CSV content and puts it as anchor href, then adds the `download` attribute to anchor where the value is filename.
You could check preview here http://jsfiddle.net/uF4H7/12/ (click "download" next to "Alert CSV")

Comment: is there a way to do this without opening a new window?

Comment: Did the second approach helped?

Comment: the second approach was exactly what i was looking for - thanks!

Comment: actaully a follow-up question: why is the file downloaded as 'download.csv' and not 'data-visualization.csv'?

Comment: In which browser? I tested it in FF and Chrome and there was data-visualization.csv. If this problem persists, try to remove the line `$(this).attr('download', "data-visualisation.csv");` from js and add the `download="data-visualisation.csv"` attribute to anchor.

Comment: im using chrome, ive tried both your methods but still downloading as 'download.csv'- i have the newest version of chrome. this is odd.

Comment: looks like its a known bug:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816005/anchor-tag-download-attribute-not-working-bug-in-chrome-35-0-1916-114

Answer (score 3):

```
exporting: {
           buttons: {
               contextButton: {
                   menuItems: [{
                       textKey: 'downloadXLS',
                       onclick: function () {
                           this.downloadXLS();
                       }
                   }, {
                       textKey: 'downloadCSV',
                       onclick: function () {
                           this.downloadCSV();
                       }
                   }]
               }
           }
       },
```

> You can add this options directly when you are creating highchart.

Answer (score 3):

Asiya Shaikh's suggestion only worked for me once I added the following Highcharts plugin:

```
<script src="http://highcharts.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js"></script>
```

Which is a little weird considering how the plugin home page mentions nothing of the downloadXLS(); function.

If that doesn't work, you should also try using:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

You can use the [EXPORT-CSV plugin homepage](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data) as a reference, but as I said it doesn't mention downloadXLS().